# Pandas: If item in list equals column value, append

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question about some code using `python3`/`pandas`.

I have a list

```
mylist = [2,6,7]
```

and a dataframe

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
```

Now I want to check, if an item of `mylist` equals a value of column `C` in `df`. If it does, make a new `df2` with the rows that gave a match.

```
col = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=col)
for x in mylist:
    if len(df.loc[df['C'] == x])>=1:
        df2.append(df.loc[df['C'] == x])
```

Unfortunately, that does not work (I don't get any output).
My expected output (`df2`) would be:

```
index   A   B       C   D
2       foo two     2   4
6       foo one     6   12
7       foo three   7   14
```

Comment: `df2 = df[df.C.isin(mylist)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify that you want `df2`to equal your append statement:

```
df2 = df2.append(df.loc[df['C'] == x])
```